# Which one is better for making a calendar, illustrator or indesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

Someone help me!
I would like to know which one is better for making a calendar... illustrator or indesign and why? I have to make one, but not sure which program to use.

Comment: Hey tzur, welcome to GD.SE! You've gotten some good answers already, hopefully one of those helps you. If so, be sure to check the little box next to the one you think best answers your question. If none of them answer your question, I'd encourage you to edit your question and add more details and context (specifically, what you're using the calendar for - print? web?). If you have any questions about how the site works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

InDesign. It has stylesheets for your text (dates, days of the week, month names) and for your tables (the calendar structure itself) and has master-page items that can be used on all pages consistently. illustrator would be fine to make the nice image that goes on the other half of the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

inDesign and use the following script:
http://calendarwizard.sourceforge.net/

Has saved me many hours of toil and frustration.